# Могу ли я уменьшить переменную i в цикле for

Tags: python, for

Допустим, у меня есть цикл

```
for i in range(10):
```

С помощью чего я могу в нужный момент уменьшит эту переменную i на 1, то есть сделать откат? i -= 1 не работает, т.к. к возвращению к циклу i вернет свое значение + 1.

UPD: 
СПАСИБО ВАМ БОЛЬШОЕ! Я попробовал через цикл while и все сработало.

Comment: Лучше `while` использовать в этом случае

Comment: Каковая задача стоит?

Comment: [Нельзя просто так отойти на шаг назад.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064778/7791165)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В python цикл `for` перебирает коллекцию и не имеет параметров для установки "шага" потому понятие "возврата на шаг назад" здесь нет.
Как уже порекомендовал [Александр](/users/255680/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80) следует воспользоваться циклом `while`

```
i = 0
while i < 10
  # Ваш код

  if i == 6 # любое Ваше условие для возврата на шаг назад
     i -= 1
  if i == 5 # любое Ваше условие для повтора текущего шага
     pass
  if i == 7 # любое Ваше условие для еще какого-нибудь действия
     i == 9
  else      # во всех остальных случаях движемся дальше
     i += 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую!